# customizar RoleProvider sem uso de Membership ou do ASP.NET Identit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Bom dia.
Minha duvida e a seguinte tenho a parte de autenticação do meu sistema feita sem uso de Membership ou do ASP.NET Identit. e queria fazer ou uso do método [Authorize] já peguei um exemplo no google onde fiz o seguinte

[image: PermissoesFiltro]
[image: PermissaoProvider]
[image: erro]
[image: web.config]

Comment: Será mais fácil se você fornecer trechos de código, e exemplificar a sua dúvida, do que apenas colocar prints da sua tela. Dessa maneira, existem mais chances de que alguém compreenda o seu problema e possa lhe ajudar.

Comment: no caso eu queria saber se da para fazer uso da classe RoleProvider para autorização se usar Membership ou ASP.NET Identit. Só usando a autenticação simple que eu ja tinha feito. pq eu quero definir niveis de acesso a determinados grupos de usuarios e ja usava  o [Authorize] no controller mas ai eu nao consigo definir um usuario para cada local tipo admin e user. No meu caso todo usuario autenticado acessa tudo. e eu quero limitar isso mas nao sei como...

Comment: no trecho "autorização se usar Membership" é sem usar errei!

Comment: O código está correto, mas tem algo estranho na configuração. Vou tentar uma resposta.

Comment: caso queira mais informações ... eu coloco...

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o código da implementação está ok, mas tem algo esquisito na configuração. Você está usando parâmetros do `MembershipProvider` pra configurar um `RoleProvider`.

Eu faria assim:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="PermissaoProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="PermissaoProvider" type="Site.Security.PermissaoProvider" connectionStringName="conexao" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    ...
  <system.web>
  ...
<configuration>
```

Comment: tentei da forma que você colocou mas não consegui quanto aos "parâmetros do MembershipProvider" que vc colocou seriam os parametros de autenticação?

Comment: Sim. `EnablePasswordRetrieval` e `EnablePasswordReset` não são parâmetros do `RoleProvider`.

Comment: Não eu implementei uma autenticação simples "própria"  e venho usando ela pois em minhas aplicações eu só tinha um tipo de usuario o admin entao decorava meu controller com a tag [Authorize] e so os usuarios autenticados faziam uso  e agora terei os perfis  user e admin mas nao sei como limitar ou perfil user sem mudar todo o esquema de autenticação que eu já havia criado para a autenticação do Membership

Comment: `[Authorize]` aceita um parâmetro chamado `Roles`. Fica assim: `[Authorize(Roles = "Usuario")]`. Quanto ao seu problema, é alguma coisa relativa à configuração. Entendi o que você quer, mas há um problema de entendimento do conceito. Um `RoleProvider` gerencia as *roles* e permissões, e o `Membership` gerencia usuários. Você está juntando as duas coisas.

Comment: entao nao tem como usar roles se nao estiver usando a autenticacao do Membership  correto? eu achei aquele exemplo que mostrei no google e achei que dava para usar uma coisa independente da outra... vc sabe o que devo buscar para resolver o problema de permissoes?

Comment: Você pode escrever apenas o `RoleProvider`. Ele funciona com a implementação *default* do `MembershipProvider`. Apenas atente às configurações. A configuração de um é diferente para o outro.

Comment: ok vou continuar tentando obrigado pela atenção.